# Symfony 3.4 : I can't connect to the database (parameters.yml and php bin/console)

Tags: database, symfony

I regained control of an "old" website (developed with Symfony 3.4). I had restored my Mac (now under macOS Monterey 12.6). And I recreated a Symfony environment (composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition psf_gironde) and pasted the original project into the new htdocs. Everything seems to work fine except the blog page. There is a problem with the database access. I got several errors like "Unknown Database...", "Access denied for user..." etc.

[One of the errors displayed when accessing the blog page. Browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj3M4.png)

I understood that the database was not created. But when I run a "php bin/console doctrine:database:create" I only get a list of errors as long like a day without bread. But in fact I think it's the php bin/console command that is causing me trouble. No matter what I try ("cache:clear", "about", "server:run"), the result is always this famous long list of errors.

[Extract from the "php bin/console" errors list. Screenshot of the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubNQW.png)

The version of php, according to the terminal (php -v) is 8.1.3. The one selected on cpanel is 7.4.
My long research on the Web leads me to believe that there could be a compatibility problem with the php version. But I don't know how to change it using the command line.

Otherwise I had found an idea here by installing php-xml (apt install php-xml). I ran the command but I get the error "*The operation could not be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.*" And there too I have no idea :/

Could someone please help me? I am not an expert and I am under pressure.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: It seems like you don't have vendor, try composer install first to install all dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that was proposed to me was to create a Symfony environment by **installing a Symfony Local Web Server** (https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html). Then, we create the database via the **symfony console doctrine:database:create** command and not this one : php bin/console doctrine:database:create